# How can consumer check if the schema registry is reachable before getting data from Kafka broker?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

As I know, a Kafka consumer will go to schema registry to fetch and cache data schema for future uses at 1st time deserializing the avro data from broker.

Would it be possible for a consumer process to check first if the schema registry is reachable (like network issue or registry accidentally down or whatever) before all these begin?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CachedSchemaRegistryClient` or `HttpURLConnection` class outside of the Consumer loop to do a HTTP connection.